# fix concatenated json insert space between joined objects

Tags: json, bash, macos, sed, terminal

I concatenated a lot of json files into another file.

This means there's lots of json (all on one line) that isn't valid, e.g.

```
{"foo":"bar"}{"extra":["stuff"]}
```

I want to replace the `}{` with `},\n{`, so running on the above file would produce

```
{"foo":"bar"},
{"extra":"stuff"}
```

I tried

```
sed 's/}{/},\n{/g' items.json
```

It doesn't put the newline, only `,n`

Comment: Had to use `sed $'s/}{/},\\\n{/g'`